# If there is no distinction between classes and objects why doesn't this code work?

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I was always taught that in Javascript there is no distinction between objects and classes. Then can someone explain why this code generate error:

```
var firstObj = function() {};

firstObj.prototype.sayHi = function() {
document.write("Hi!");
};

firstObj.sayHi();
```

Whereas this one works:

```
var firstObj = function() {};

firstObj.prototype.sayHi = function() {
document.write("Hi!");
};

new firstObj().sayHi();
```

What's the difference? Why isn't the first one working?

Comment: Classes do not exist in javascript...

Comment: @jondavidjohn - Not yet, but `class` is a [future reserved word](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.2), so stay tuned! :)

Answer (score 4):

The key issue here is that your `firstObj` variable is a `Function` object, not a `firstObj` object.  This is a subtle distinction, but the type of object determines which prototype it inherits.

The prototype is like a template that is applied to newly created objects of a particular type.  You must create a `firstObj` object (usually with `new` which invokes the constructor and assigns a prototype) in order to have that template applied to it.  In the first example, your `firstObj` variable is a `Function` object, not a `firstObj` object so it has the prototype of a `Function` not of anything else..

In your second example, you actually create a `firstObj` object so it inherits the prototype for that type of object.

If you want the method applied in your first example so it works on the function object you've already created, just put the method directly on your already existing function object, not on the prototype.

Comment: in the first example, firstObj.prototype.sayHi is defined. so when calling firstObj.sayHi(), why wouldn't the js engine just 'walk up the prototype' chain and find a reference to it?

Comment: @sshen - Because `firstObj` is just a Function object.  It isn't a `firstObj` object.  You have to actually create a `firstObj` object to inherit the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference *in the language* between objects and classes<sup>1</sup>. However, there is a big difference between one kind of object and another. In the first case:

```
firstObj.sayHi();
```

you are trying to access the `sayHi` property of `firstObj`, which is a `Function` object that does not have such a property. (You could, however, do `firstObj.prototype.sayHi()`.)

In the second case:

```
new firstObj().sayHi();
```

you are first invoking the `new` operator on the `firstObj` object, which evaluates to a new object. That new object has `firstObj` as it's `constructor` property and a prototype equal to the `prototype` property of `firstObj`. You are then accessing the `sayHi` property of that returned object, which succeeds because `sayHi` is in the prototype chain for that object.

<sup>1</sup> Technically, JavaScript doesn't have classes<sup>2</sup> (in the traditional sense), just constructor functions that are usually called "classes".

<sup>2</sup> However, `class` is a [future reserved word](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.2).

Answer (score 0):

A function is just a function until `new` is issued. At that point, a `Function Object` is created based on the prototype for the function. That is why you will not see the `sayHi` method present in the first version.

Also, `firstObj` is a function, and not an object, so you need to invoke it to actually have anything happen. `firstObj` will not actually invoke the function, you must use `firstObj()`.

Further, there are ways to have the prototype used without explicitly requiring the `new` keyword. This is done in a number of popular frameworks (such as jQuery). It is done by checking to see if `new` was used, and if it was not, then it `new`s one up for you on the spot:

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/Gx3T6/)***

```
var firstObj = function() {
 if( !(this instanceof firstObj) ){
  return new firstObj();   
 }
};

firstObj.prototype.sayHi = function() {
 alert("hi");
};

firstObj().sayHi();
```

Comment: This is misleading at best. `firstObj` is an instance of `Function` (i.e., `firstObj.prototype === Function`). And `Function` instances are most certainly objects. Also, `(new firstObj).sayHi()` (without the parens after `firstObj`) works just as well as OP's second code. The parens are needed because otherwise it would be evaluated as `new ((firstObj.sayHi)())`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant when I said a `Function object`. A `Function` instance is an object. However, `firstObj.prototype === Function` is false. Moreover, `typeof new firstObj === object` whereas `typeof firstObj === function`. Using parenthesis in that fashion causes `new firstObj` to become an expression which is why that works. `var fO = new firstObj;fO.sayHi()` would be another way of looking at that. When you use `new`, you do not need to invoke the function, it is implicit.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong about `firstObj.prototype`; I meant that the prototype of `firstObj` (not the `prototype` property) is `Function` (`firstObj instanceof Function` is `true`). So it is `firstObj`, not `new firstObj` that is a `Function` object. (`(new firstObj()) instanceof Function` is `false`, as is `(new firstObj) instanceof Function`.) Your second paragraph has additional misleading information: all functions in JavaScript are, in fact, objects (`firstObj instanceof Object` is also `true`). (After all, that's why it can have a `prototype` property.)

Answer (score 0):

when you write this:

```
var firstObj = function() {};
```

you only define a constructor function, thus you need to use the key word `new` for the new objects created with this constructor function.